# Как на PHP связать сайт и тг-бота?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, веб-сайт

Занимаюсь написанием сайта на PHP (нулевой уровень работы с ним ранее). Концепция первой странички такая: пользователь нажимает на кнопку, далее его перекидывает на другую страницу, и в чат telegram отправляется от бота сообщение о вызове.

- Как написать тг бота с сайтом? (для оформления сайта использую css и html в части кода)
- Как связать отправку сообщения ботом и нажатие кнопки?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$token = "TOKEN";
$chat_id = "chatID";


$name = trim($_POST["fullname"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);

$success = 'Ваша заявка была успешно отправлена.';
$error = 'Произошла ошибка повторите пожалуйста.';


$telegram = "$subject\nИмя: $name\nТелефон: $phone";

$data = [
   'chat_id' => $chat_id,
   'text' => $telegram,
 'parse_mode' => 'HTML'
 ];
$response = 
 file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?" . 
 http_build_query($data) );

 if ($response) {
    echo $success;
 } else {
     echo $error;
 }
```